# Pivoting dataset from long format to wide format (large dataset)

Tags: r

I have a df that looks similar to this:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Disease = c("heart failure", "Hypertension", 
"cancer", "heart failure"), Patient_Id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

and I want to pivot it to a wide format, so that it looks like this:

```
> dput(df1)
structure(list(Patient_ID = 1:2, heart.failure = c(1L, 1L), Hypertension = 1:0, 
    cancer = 0:1), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L
))
```

I tried using `reshape()`, but since my real dataset is very large, the code takes an extremely long time to compile. Is there a faster method?

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier with `table` from `base R`

```
table(df[2:1])
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_wider(df, names_from = Disease, values_from = Disease, 
    values_fn = ~ +(length(.x) > 0), values_fill = 0)
```

Comment: Works beautifully--thank you so much !